# How to Disable Windows File Explorer from Automatically Launching Webpage

Tags: windows, browser, webpage, windows-explorer

I'm not liking Windows File Explorer's feature to automatically launch webpages. How can this be disabled?

For example, in Windows File Explorer, type "StackOverflow" in search. Since there is no file named "Stackoverflow" it will automatically launch Stackoverflow.com. This is really annoying because typos or empty results cause unexpected waits, launching of undesired webpages, privacy leaks, and other security issues. This feature should be an opt-in, not an opt-out.

Comment: Have you performed any web searches on doing this? What have you found?

Comment: I did due diligence before posting. One would think this was a well documented question, hence your question. I found nothing.

Comment: If you read the info on posting good questions in the help center, it recommends to include your searches in your question. When I type "Stack Overflow" into the path box it brings up a google search of stack overflow (but not the web page). If I type stack overflow into the search box it only searches the file system. Can you workaround by just using the search box?

Comment: Your idea to use the search box instead of the path box can sometimes be a helpful workaround. However, I choose not to use the search box because it can return many results which is sometimes a good thing and sometimes not. I have to insist that the desired answer contain instructions on how to disable File Explorer from launching webpages.